# How to get instance of PHP-DI container from any class I want?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, php-di

I am using PHP-DI 6 Container in my PHP Project. At the very begging of my program I just initialize the container and get `Application` class with all dependencies injected.

```
    $container   = new Container();
    $application = $container->get(Application::class);

    $application->initialize();
    $application->run();
```

On the image below you can see classes that I use in my project.

[image: class diagram]

Asterisk Dispatcher gets injected into Application class.

```
private $asteriskDispatcher;

public function __construct(AsteriskDispatcher $asteriskDispatcher)
{
    $this->asteriskDispatcher = $asteriskDispatcher;
}
```

Then, inside `AsteriskDispatcher` class I need to create a list of Asterisk Manager instances, which is going to contain some dependencies as well in near future.

I don't want to inherit container through the all classes. Is there a way to initialize PHP-DI container as singleton, so I can use it any moment I want to create some objects?

This is how I am doing this right now, I just create a new instance of PHP-DI container inside my `AsteriskDispatcher` class and this looks so damn awful.

```
class AsteriskDispatcher implements AsteriskDispatcherInterface
{
    private $listOfAsteriskManagers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $configurations = AsteriskConnectionsConfiguration::$connectionsConfiguration;

        $this->listOfAsteriskManagers = new \SplDoublyLinkedList();

        $container = new Container();

        foreach ($configurations as $configuration)
        {
            $this->listOfAsteriskManagers->push($container->make(AsteriskManager::class,
                array('configuration' => $configuration)));
        }
    }
}
```

I really want to understand how can I use PHP-DI container without breaking SOLID principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/container.html#make):

> **If you need to use the make() method inside a service, or a controller, or whatever, it is recommended that you type-hint against FactoryInterface *.** That avoids coupling your code to the container. DI\FactoryInterface is automatically bound to DI\Container so you can inject it without any configuration.

<sup>*emphasis mine</sup>

So you should change your `AsteriskDispatcher` constructor to be like:

```php
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory) {
  // your code ...
  // more of your code ...

  $factory->make(AsteriskManager::class, ['configuration' => $configuration]);

  // the rest of your code.

}
```

PS: [Singletons](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonsAreEvil) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) [evil](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/06/27/singletons-must-die.html) (mostly).

Comment: And what if I need a container instance in my bootstrap that is a functional code? AFAIK the container can only inject itself into an OOP code.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand. Can’t help you.